# Remove duplicates from text document with line which follows the duplicate

Tags: c#, duplicates

I'm wondering about two things, I want to remove duplicate lines from text document each time I add new string to write it to the text file. Need not to disturb the order and keep uppermost of duplicates. I use it inside:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
```

First I want to ask, if my text document contains about 100 000 lines or more. Here is two  samples how can I do it, and I did not think that these codes can handle large file, but it looks like it works without hang:

this one works, but not with KeyDown event:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(mypath);
File.WriteAllLines(mypath, lines.Distinct().ToArray());
```

and this one works with KeyDown event and large content:

```
File.WriteAllLines(mypath, File.ReadAllLines(mypath).Distinct().ToArray());
```

What is a difference in meaning of implementation if I have same result with both, except that I can use last with KeyDown event?

And question two:

How can I remove not only duplicate lines but also at the same time lines which is next after duplicate, for example document content is:

```
1
2
3
1
4
5
4
4
6
7
8
3
9
```

then process this way:

```
1
2
3
1 /// remove
4 /// remove because it follows a previous duplicate  
5
4 /// remove
4 /// remove
6 /// remove because it follows a previous duplicate  
7
8
3 /// remove
9 /// remove because it follows a previous duplicate
```

So desired result should be:

```
1
2
3    
5
7
8
```

Comment: Have you tried using List<string> instead of string[]?? With .ToList()..

Comment: @ArchAngel  Hello, yes also works with KeyDown event

Comment: Why did you remove the line 7 (containing 4). How is 4 a duplicate, if you already deleted line 5?

Comment: BTW, you can use `File.WriteAllLines(mypath, File.ReadLines(mypath).Distinct());` instead of `File.WriteAllLines(mypath, File.ReadAllLines(mypath).Distinct().ToArray());`. IMHO, it is a better way to write it.

Comment: `this one works, but not with KeyDown event:`
What does that mean? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Vikhram Hello, I don't know why, but hangs if file is large

Comment: The File.ReadAllLines() Method wasn't designed to read large text file only small ones, use a StreamReader for larger files..

Comment: Why do you remove the 2nd "4"? and 3rd "4"?

Answer (score 1):

This might help,

```
 List<string> lines = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "1", "4", "5", "4", "4", "6", "7", "8", "3", "9" };

            var duplicateIndexes = lines.Select((name, index) => new { name, index })
            // select list items name and index
                            .GroupBy(g => g.name)
            // group them with their name
                            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            // if name counts more than one
                            .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1), (g, item) => item.index);
            // select but skip first one, because if we need to 
            // count the number as duplicate we should see it before
            // so first number we see is not a duplicate.

            foreach (var item in duplicateIndexes.OrderBy(v=> v))
            {
                lines[item] = "null"; // we can't directly remove because indexes changes so I decide to set a null string
                lines[item + 1] = "null"; // you said after first duplicate the item should be removed also, ok item + 1 then
            }
            lines.RemoveAll(x => x == "null"); // then remove all nulls
```

**Result;**
[image]
That should give the result, (inform me if there is better solution without using replace strings with "null"),

Hope helps,

Comment: It works, explain the issue please. See result image also.

Comment: item == Error = 'The name item does not exist in the current context'.. Can see why it doesn't work now, you have name and item in the code snippet and you only have item in the image.. But it still give not values on mine..

Comment: Ahh, my bad. Tried to give a meaningful name :) Now there won't be error. It gives the duplicate indexes not the values. Than it change that indexes and the following one on the original list with "null". After foreach it remove all "null". If you are using this answer, you should check lines List after removeAll. @ArchAngel

Comment: Your code snippet is faster then mine but it's basically the same thing mine does, except I have the values also.. So your answer is the fastest and shortest one here.. +1..

Comment: You can get values by returning name inside linq statement. :) Thanks.

Comment: I use a custom class to return index and values.. I'll change my code snippet so it, looks like yours, but a little different..

Comment: Thx for the help in in optimizing my code snippet, either way, yours and mine are basically the same now, except for the load text file statment.. And I gave you the credit for helping with my code snippet..

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your question, I am seriously confused about. As far as my knowledge goes, this code should behave the exact same, because it is evaluated into the same MSIL-code.

The second part of your question: You cannot do this by easily using a given function. You have to iterate over the lines, find duplicates by yourself, then remove them by yourself and remove the next line as well. I have not tested the following code as I am writing from a non-windows device, although it should give you an example of how to work it out (and most probably should work):

```
var duplicateLines = new List<string> ();
var acceptedLines = new List<string> ();

for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
    var line = lines[i];
    if (!acceptedLines.Contains (line)) {
        acceptedLines.Add (line);
        continue;
    } else {
        duplicateLines.Add (line);
        if (lines.Length > i) {
            duplicateLines.Add (lines [++i]);
            continue;
        }
    }    
}
```

Note that this is not that good performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the old fashioned way without `File.ReadAllLines` and the filename passed as `args[0]`

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<String> linesAfterFiltering = new List<String>();
        Boolean skipNextLineDueToFoundDuplicate = false;

        String curLine = null;

        using(StreamReader r = new StreamReader(args[0]))
        {
            while(null != (curLine = r.ReadLine().Trim()))
            {
                // Check it curLine is a duplicate
                if(linesAfterFiltering.Contains(curLine))
                {
                    skipNextLineDueToFoundDuplicate = true;
                    continue;
                }

                // We have to skip one line since we found a duplicate previously
                if(skipNextLineDueToFoundDuplicate)
                {
                    skipNextLineDueToFoundDuplicate = false;
                    continue;
                }

                // We found a new value that we don't have to skip => save it
                linesAfterFiltering.Add(curLine);
            }
        }
    }
```

The desired result is then stored in `linesAfterFiltering`

Answer (score -1):

This linq code snippet should give you all the duplicated values and filter it as you desire:

```
//Small Text files
var originallist = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).ToList();
//Large Text files
var originallist = new List<string>();
string line = "";
var sr = new StreamReader(filename);
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   originallist.Add(line);
}
sr.close();

// Filter and sort the list and returns the duplicated indexes..
var duplicateIndexes = originallist.Select((name, index) => new { name, index }).GroupBy(g => g.name).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1), (g, item) => item.index).ToList();

foreach (var itm in duplicateIndexes)
{
   originallist[itm] = null; //Replacing the duplicated item with null.
   originallist[itm + 1] = null; //Replacing the second line with null.
}
originallist.RemoveAll(x => x == null); // then remove all nulls
```

Thanks to @Berkay I figured out how to filter the list as you desire..

Comment: He doesn't ask for duplicates.

Comment: @ArchAngel should I do this  way  `originallist.Remove(i.ToString());
                    originallist.Remove(i.ToString());` and with `duplicates.Remove(itm);` I got, not sure what is wrong:
`Error CS1061 'IEnumerable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Remove' and no extension method 'Remove' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<string>' could be found`

Comment: I'm working on fixing the errors in my code snippet, wait for my update..

Comment: @ArchAngel  I have not noticed your code with minus, someone else did it. I understand that the code requires fixing the errors, and it doesn't mean that the solution is bad